# Having issues reading a .csv file present in a directory

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a following path defined where I have

```
 label_csv_file = r"C:/Users/username/Downloads/Personal Stuff/Python Directory files/Scripts/CSV Copy Scripts/label.csv"
```

I was trying to read the csv using pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
labelpd = pd.read_csv(label_csv_file)
```

I get the following error:
handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/Personal Stuff/Python Directory files/Scripts/CSV Copy Scripts/label.csv', but the file is clearly there
[image]

I blacked out my name, instead of username my name is in the path, so I don't understand why I am having the issue, I have changed the label.csv to be just label as well. Its not just pandas, I was having issues opening with even with

> open(label_csv_file, 'rb'),

where the label_csv_file path had been set, what is the issue here?

I have tried changing the file name to just label as it is already a .csv file that does not work either, I have changed the file path to just say /label, that doesn't work either

Comment: The usual behavior of the Windows file browser is to show the filename without the extension.  Since that image does show the file extension, that suggests that file name is really `label.csv.csv`

Comment: @Thoughtful_monkey `/` will work just fine, even in Windows.  Also it's a raw string, so no need for double backslashes.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have tried with just renaming it as label as well, same issue

Comment: Try adding this to your code and show us the output `import os; print(os.listdir("C:/Users/username/Downloads/Personal Stuff/Python Directory files/Scripts/CSV Copy Scripts"))`

Comment: it comes up as field.xlsx, label.xlsx

Comment: Well, then that explains it.  There is not, in fact, a file named `label.csv` in that directory.

Comment: You must have saved it as a regular Excel file, not a CSV file.

Comment: Yep ya I just thought excel saved it as an .csv file thanks a lot for your help, the file extension I couldn't see it even thru properties so was confused

Comment: I should have realized when the type column in the screenshot had Microsoft Excel instead of CSV.